# How to handle data received from unioned select statements

Tags: php, mysql

Hello I'm trying to create a search function for my website. I have this method that has the query

```
public function search_all($data)
{
    $query = [];

    $result = $this->db->query('
        SELECT blog_title FROM blog WHERE blog_title LIKE "%'. $data . '%" 
        UNION
        SELECT body FROM blog WHERE body LIKE "%'. $data . '%" 
        UNION 
        SELECT username FROM users WHERE username LIKE "%'. $data . '%"
    ');

    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) 
    {
        $query[] = $row;
    }

    $result->free();

    return $query;

    $mysqli->close();
}
```

Then I have the method that handles the user input

```
public function search()
{
    if (isset($_POST['search']))
    {
        $search_term = trim($_POST['search_term']);

        $terms = $this->search->search_all($search_term);

        foreach ($terms as $term) 
        {
            var_dump($term);
        }
    }
}
```

The search works sort of. If I search a username or a blog title it then I can echo it back like this

```
echo $term['blog_title'];
```

if I var_dump then I get something like

```
array (size=1)
    'blog_title' => string 'BillyBob' (length=8)
```

My question is why does it always retrun blog_title as the key. I thought I would have to do something like

If I want to echo the blog title

```
echo $term['blog_title'];
```

If I want to echo the username

```
echo $term['username'];
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the union of two tables either the fields of both tables should be same or the alias should be same for both the tables.

Please try this query.

```
$result = $this->db->query('
    SELECT body,blog_title,'' as username FROM blog WHERE blog_title LIKE "%'. $data . '%" OR body  LIKE "%'. $data . '%"  OR username  LIKE "%'. $data . '%"
    UNION 
    SELECT '' as body,'' as blog_title,username FROM users WHERE username LIKE "%'. $data . '%"
');
```

This query will select records when search will match with blog_title or body or username. And you will able to fetch all three fields' value for fetched records.

Comment: the username is retreived from a different table called users

Comment: Ok and is there any relation between blog and users table?

Comment: No relation. I want the user to be able to search and find either users or blog posts. I was playing on adding more unions so they could find other things as well when I ran into this issue.

Comment: For Union table field name must be same. SO in this case either you should have to execute two separate queries or alias should be same for both tables.  For eg check updated query in the answer.